# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I was trying to access my MS Database Locally so i have this DatabaseHelper.kt file which i included the Doinbackground Function, which in turn brings out this error.

[CodeSnippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwnTB.png)
06-19 15:28:45.082 18819-18819/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage() 06-19 15:28:45.082 18819-18819/? E/Zygote: v2 06-19 15:28:45.092 18819-18819/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL 06-19 15:28:45.092 18819-18819/? E/art: setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE) failed for pid 18819: Operation not permitted 06-19 15:28:47.814 18819-18819/com.example.mysqlcon E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout 06-19 15:28:47.924 18819-18819/com.example.mysqlcon E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout 06-19 15:28:47.984 18819-18862/com.example.mysqlcon E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Process: com.example.mysqlcon, PID: 18819 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/ietf/jgss/GSSManager; at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.createGssToken(TdsCore.java:4400) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.sendMSLoginPkt(TdsCore.java:1971) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:617) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.(JtdsConnection.java:371) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:144) at com.example.mysqlcon.ConnectionClass.dbConn(ConnectionClass.kt:26) at com.example.mysqlcon.DatabaseHelper$SyncData.doInBackground(DatabaseHelper.kt:36) at com.example.mysqlcon.DatabaseHelper$SyncData.doInBackground(DatabaseHelper.kt:23) at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mysqlcon-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469) at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.createGssToken(TdsCore.java:4400)  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.sendMSLoginPkt(TdsCore.java:1971)  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:617)  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.(JtdsConnection.java:371)  at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:144)  at com.example.mysqlcon.ConnectionClass.dbConn(ConnectionClass.kt:26)  at com.example.mysqlcon.DatabaseHelper$SyncData.doInBackground(DatabaseHelper.kt:36)  at com.example.mysqlcon.DatabaseHelper$SyncData.doInBackground(DatabaseHelper.kt:23)  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)  Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ietf.jgss.GSSManager at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781) at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)

... 17 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available 06-19 15:28:48.064 18819-18819/com.example.mysqlcon E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mysqlcon.InvoiceActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{11c938 V.E..... R......D 0,0-681,215} that was originally added here at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:530) at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:287) at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91) at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:325) at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:151) at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:134) at com.example.mysqlcon.DatabaseHelper$SyncData.onPreExecute(DatabaseHelper.kt:31) at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591) at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539) at com.example.mysqlcon.DatabaseHelper.getinvoices(DatabaseHelper.kt:92) at com.example.mysqlcon.InvoiceActivity.onCreate(InvoiceActivity.kt:21) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3104) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:219) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1735) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Comment: please post the full stack trace

Comment: I'm trying to post the logcat from android studio, but it's not working could you please guide?

Comment: Try to explain exactly what you were trying to achieve when the error happened and use the stack trace to support it

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) Caused by: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
Lorg/ietf/jgss/GSSManager; at
```

Either you are using an incorrect proguard specification or this class is not available because a dependency is missing.